# how to add new row or a footer in rc-table in react js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to add a new row at the end of rc-table to show total of column value.

```js
const columns = [
  {
    title: "Name",
    className: "cursor-pointer",
    dataIndex: "name",
    key: "name",
    Footer: "Total",
    align: alignLeft,
    // onHeaderCell: () => onHeaderClick('name'),
    render: (name: any) => <span className="whitespace-nowrap">{name}</span>,
  },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```html
const columns = [
  {
    title: "Name",
    className: "cursor-pointer",
    dataIndex: "name",
    key: "name",
    align: alignLeft,
    render: (name: any) => <span className="whitespace-nowrap">{name}</span>,
    footer: (data: any) => {
      let total = 0;
      data.forEach((item: any) => {
        total += item.name;
      });
      return <div>{`Total: ${total}`}</div>;
    },
  },
];
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).